# How do we know the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type?

Tags: c++, size-t, size-type

[Here is the introduction for `size_t` in cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)

> `std::size_t` can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).

I know the exact value is platform-dependent. But who decides the size of `theoretically possible object`, the compiler or the operating system, or even the computer manufacturer? Could the size of theoretically possible object be calculated or it's just decided by man-made rule?

In addition, if the machine is 64-bit, does that mean the max object size could be 2^64 bytes?

Comment: The theoretical upper limit is what your implementation can address.  A 64-bit machine with a compiler that emits 64-bit code to produce 64-bit executables can (theoretically) address amounts up to 2^64-1. The practical upper limit is less than that due to (um) practical limits, such as 32-bit programs running on a 64-bit system (if the OS supports that) only being able to address 32-bits,  quotas on how much memory an OS may allow a process to allocate,  the virtual memory (crudely, the sum of physical RAM and swap space) may be less than can be theoretically addressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But who decides the size of theoretically possible object [...] ?

The author of the "implementation" gets to decide. The implementation is a rather nebulous term that includes the compiler, run-time library, and often at least part of the OS.

> In addition, if the machine is 64-bit, does that mean the max object size could be 2^64 bytes?

Not really. You probably can't *exceed* 2<sup>64</sup>-1 bytes, but the limit may well be (normally will be, at least on machine current as of 2018 when I'm writing this) much lower than that. Many current CPUs have much smaller real limits--around 2<sup>42</sup>-1 is probably more realistic.

Answer (score 3):

It really goes both ways.

As `size_t` is the return type of the `sizeof` operator, the type also *sets* the max size of an object. For `sizeof` to work, no object can be allowed to exceed the size that `size_t` can represent.

Nothing requires a compiler to let you build a single object using *all* available memory. There might be an upper limit, which *might* be the result of the choice of types for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`.

On the other hand, with current 64-bit computers, a 64-bit `size_t` is even way larger than required, as you cannot currently fit 16 exabytes of RAM in a computer smaller than 100 meters (cubed). So much for "theoretically possible". :-}

Comment: Even if there was enough space, current CPUs don't use all bits of a 64 bit address word (and afaik this is not just missing bits).

Comment: Correct, and it has something to do with the fact that you would need *a billion* 16 GB RAM modules to fill out the exabytes. And I only have 4 slots in my PC. :-(

Comment: It was a reasonable decission. Problem is modern computers **do** approach this limit already. Although I doubt you or me will be affected in the near future. But who knows. very soon 640KiB were **not** enough.

Answer (score 2):

> *if the machine is 64-bit, does that mean the max object size could be 2^64 bytes?*

The issue here is that a "*64-bit machine*" is insufficient information to answer the question. The main limiting factor here is how much *sequential memory* the instruction set can address *at any given time*. It is decided by the designer of the CPU architecture.

x86 has a number of execution modes: real mode (16 bit [segmented](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Memory/M77_0330_flat_vs_segmented.htm)), 32-bit mode and 64-bit mode. In each of these modes the size of the largest sequentially addressable area of memory is different. In real mode 1MB could be addressed, but only 64KB sequentially, hence `size_t` is 16 bits. In other modes the entire address range can be addressed sequentially.

It doesn't matter that a 64-bit processor can today physically address 48 bits, because it still operates on full 64-bit offsets and can *theoretically* address a 64-bit-long object. Hence the width of `size_t` there would still be 64 bits.

In commodity processors the width of `size_t` usually corresponds to the size of the accumulator register, since that defines the maximum possible offset the CPU can address.